# populate files from a folder into a dropdown list

Tags: php, html

I am trying to populate some files from an network folder into a dropdown list for selecting by a user for importing the file into a CAM system. 
The problem is that it keeps showing {$file} in the dropdown list.

It's is for a program that makes toolpaths for moulding. The user should be able to select a tool and a holder and then the system creates the tool and imports the holder.

```html
     <div class="dropdown-content">
             <p align="center">
             <label>Holders</label>
             <select id="menu1">

    <?php  
$dir = "Z:/CNC 文件/刀库+刀柄数据/PowerMill刀柄库/*.pmlth";  

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents  
if (is_dir($dir)) {  
   if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {  
       while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {  
           print "<option value=\"{$file}\">{$file}</option>";  
       }  
       closedir($dh);  
   }  
}  
?> 
  </select>
```

Comment: _“The problem is that it keeps showing {$file} in the dropdown list.”_ - that is not reproducible with the code you have shown - are you sure that is the _exact_ code? Or is it actually maybe using single quotes as string delimiters with the `print` statement that outputs the option element?

Answer (score -1):

I am using bootstrap for [styling.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/)

Bootstrap dropdowns require some js files to work properly. You can get the cdn from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/)

```
<div class="dropdown show">
   <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" 
     id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- 
     expanded="false">
     Dropdown link
     </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">

  <?php

     $directory = 'your_directory/'; //Your directory 

     foreach(glob($directory.'*.*') as $file_path)
     {
        $filename = pathinfo($file_path)['filename'];
        echo "<a class='dropdown-item' href='$file_path'>$filename</a>";
     }
    ?>

  </div>
 </div>
```

We are reading every from a directory using [glob()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) and looping through every entry. `$file_path` will have every file with its path. We have to find a way to get the filename from the path.

We can get an array of the path using [pathinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php). `pathinfo()` return an associative array, to get filename we will get the value with key `filename`.

> $filename is the actual filename without any extension. eg. *myfile.txt*, filename will be *myfile*

Comment: Hi Sujeet. It doesn't work. Under the dropdown link there is some coding saying: $filename";}?>   Any idea what why?

Comment: @BrianAndersen I updated my answer and added some explanation. I hope you get it.